# PDFBox in Kotlin - Output of an Rectangle Field of an PDF File

Tags: string, kotlin, output, pdfbox

Its my first time i'm posting here, so sorry if i did something wrong.
My english is also not the best at the moment.

I'm new at coding and did start with some usefull Tutorials at Youtube.

My first Project should get some data out of an pdf-file.
I've used therefor PDFBox and it works well for me.

The only problem i cant solve at the moment is:

The extracted data are 4 tables in the pdf, ive used extractbyarea and set the right ints (x, y, w, h).
The data is written in an output, to this point it works well for me.

I got a string called "daten61". But if i'm using println(daten61) i got the string
shown with linebreaks. I want to use it like:

09.08 3931 15:59 00:46

and not like:

09.08

3931

15:59

00:46

Ive tried trim, replace, whatever ... it wont work.
Any other solutions for it? Someone well inside of PDFBox to can help to solve the problem?
Further i want to use the String like [09.08,3931,15:59,00:46] to start the next step of my project.

Thanks!

Code ive used:

```
val document = File("C://test//test1.pdf")
val doc = PDDocument.load(document)
val stripper = PDFTextStripperByArea()
stripper.sortByPosition = true

val output = ""
val rect = Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
stripper.addRegion(output, rect)


val firstPage = doc.getPage(0)
stripper.extractRegions(firstPage)

return (stripper.getTextForRegion(output))
```

/After println(output) ive got the Data in 4 rows

Comment: `output.replace("\\s".toRegex(), " ")`

Comment: OK thanks for that fast answer! I'm gonna try it in five hours after my work and send out a message.

Comment: Its not working, and now i'm realy confused. If i add it on println(output) i got the right result, but not if i use it in the function. :/

Comment: Strings are immutable you might want to consider that.

Comment: Yeah .. i'm trying to change some things in my code now to do the replacement in one time. alot to learn i have